# send email with awk output columns

Tags: linux, awk

Can you help me please to send email if column $3 greater than 100 for example?

```
   host@root:> report_alias  | awk '{ if($3 >= 100) { mailx -s "FILES REPORT" < "FLOW" $1,$2,$3 " has problems" example@host.ro ;}}'
    awk: { if($3 >= 100) { mailx -s "FILES REPORT" < "FLOW" $1,$2,$3 " has problems" example@host.ro ;}}
    awk:                                                      ^ syntax error
    awk: { if($3 >= 100) { mailx -s "FILES REPORT" < "FLOW" $1,$2,$3 " has problems" example@host.ro ;}}
    awk:                                                                                     ^ syntax error
    awk: { if($3 >= 100) { mailx -s "FILES REPORT" < "FLOW" $1,$2,$3 " has problems" example@host.ro ;}}
    awk:
```

**Output of the "report alias"**

```
Flow REPORT 1 3,450 has problems
Flow REPORT 2 3,154 has problems
Flow REPORT 3 134 has problems
Flow REPORT 4 134 has problems
Flow REPORT 5 has problems
Flow REPORT 6 has problems
```

Comment: you are trying to execute `mailx` which is not an awk's built-in. Try `awk '$3>=100{system("echo \"I am executing a system command because \""$3);next}' input`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
report_alias |
awk '$3 >= 100 { print "FLOW" $1, $2, $3 " has problems"}' |
mailx -s "FILES REPORT" example@host.ro
```

This will send an empty message if there is no output from Awk.  A common workaround is to save the output to a temporary file, check if it's empty, and then only if not, send a message.

```
#!/bin/sh

t=$(mktemp -t report_alias.XXXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -f $t' EXIT
trap 'exit 1' HUP INT TERM

report_alias |
awk '$3 >= 100 { print "FLOW" $1, $2, $3 " has problems"}' >"$t"

if [ -s "$t" ]; then
    mailx -s "FILES REPORT" example@host.ro <"$t"
fi
```